# How to set CheckedListBox items to checked by default

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, checkedlistbox

Is there an option in Visual Studio to set all items in a CheckedListBox to checked by default? By this I mean I would like all items to be checked upon start up, and the user can unselect items as needed.

If not, is my only option to set all items to checked programatically inside the constructor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it programmatically after populating the `Items`

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

Comment: I think that's what I have to do. Not an issue - but surprised Visual Studio doesn't offer that property, or I am unbelievably blinded to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
       {
         checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(i, true);
       }  

    }
```

Comment: I'm using a CheckedListBox not a regular CheckBox. I can do this for a check box, but for some reason don't see this property for the checkedlistbox.

Comment: I don't understand how this is upvoted. Where is that property `isChecked` ? Can you upload a image? also I've never seen any property in .Net with camelCase!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the question was saying checkbox before the user edit the question.

Comment: I don't recall ever typing checkbox.

Comment: Question is never edited. Here is the [proof](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25570739/revisions). I'd say you got upvotes for a crap answer. And still you're not ready to accept it. Blaming the OP!

Comment: They did the same mistake as me. those who upvoted were just thinking the OP was talking about checkbox (:

Comment: In all fairness, it was a simple mistake and I do appreciate the help. If I were looking for a checkbox, that was a perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this i have used in VB.net

At the time of adding Items in `CheckedListBox` use below code :

```vb
For i As Integer = 0 To Dt.Rows.Count - 1
    CLB_FolderList.Items.Add(Dt.Rows(i)("Source_FolderName").ToString(),True)
Next
```

Comment: The question is tagged with C#, so please try to propose solution in that language.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    checkedListBox..Items.Add(Dt.Rows(i)("Source_FolderName").ToString(), true);
}

Hi Peter,
please check above code for C# when you are adding item in Control please above code.

Thanks